# Cover Effect CSS

Tags: html, css, effect

On this site http://rushir.co/ I would like to make the Title (the slide.js) fixed, like the background is, so that when you scroll the "Who I Am" comes up to cover it. What do I do?

Also, I've somehow managed to make the Twitter and Email links fixed but I can't seem to get the "Who I Am" to cover it when it scrolls.
What do I do?

If the View Source isn't enough the code is on GitHub here https://github.com/rushir/rushir.github.io

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I tried that, it made the title fixed but at the top not in the middle of the page where it was before, also the links to Twitter and Email went away. (You can see here http://rushir.co/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve your problem you got to remove the "style = margin-top: -250px" from your nav element:

```
<nav style="margin-top: -250">

to

<nav>
```

Then put in your css file on the nav closure: position: fixed or whatever you want. Example:

```
 nav {                                                                                    
      position:fixed;
      margin-top:0;// Or what ever value you want                                                                                                                                                                              
      width: 100%;                                                                                         
      text-align: center;                                                                                  
      left:0;                                                                                              
      top:0;                                                                                               
 }
```

The left: 0 and top: 0 is to make the elements don't disapear in firefox when they are fixed positioned.

This are the kind of problem that we ran when we put inline css code in our html tags. Properties that are declare in html tags cannot be overwrited later in our .css file unless we modify the .html file directly or we overwrite it using the !important hack (which is not recomendable).

e).

Extra: To center the links on the top-center of the page, replace the blocks as the same selectors with the following ones and you are done:

```
nav {
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    left:0;
    top:0 
}

nav ul {
    display: block;
    line-height: -20;
    vertical-align: center;
    width:inherit; 
    text-align:center;
}
nav ul li {
        list-style: none;
        margin: 30px 30px 50px; 
        margin: 1.875rem 1.875rem 3.125rem;
        font-family: "Lato", Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: .8125em;
        font-weight: 400;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        display:inline-block; 
}
```

I hope it helped :). Cheers.

Comment: Ok I did what you said but now when you scroll the title and the links are not "covered", instead they are on top of the "Who I Am" section. http://rushir.co/ also, how do I make the nav links (Twitter and Email) be in the center instead of left aligned?

Comment: Sorry i can't comprehend what are you trying to accomplish, could you please provide me with an more explicit explanation, also please, update your guthub repository with the current problem so i could see more in detail what is what you want, that would help alot :).

Comment: I'm wanting the "Who I am" section to be on top of the title when you scroll down. Right now, for some reason when you scroll down, the Title (slide.js) is staying on top of the "Who I Am section", the opposite of what I want. I have updated the GitHub repository.

Comment: Just put on your .title class the property "z-index: 0" and in your .who class put "position: relative" and "z-index: 1", that will tell that  the z-axis position of the title to be lower than the who section making the title always hide begin the .who section, notice that you can put any value in the "z-index" property and achieve the same result as always the .title element have a lower value than the  .who section.

Comment: Awesome, it worked! Now last thing - how do I get the links ("Twitter" and "Email") to be in the center of the page, right under the Title? Thanks for your help!

Comment: I will put the the last request in the first answer since there is the only place that i can put code.